# why entity manager is not thread safe in container manage?

Tags: java, jpa, oas

Why entity manager is not thread safe in container manage?
Does oracle application server support entity manager to be thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EJB standard doesn't allow for/support multithreaded EJBs, thus there's no need for the entitymanager to be threadsafe as it's never supposed to need that functionality.